# Plotting great circle lines in Cesium (just getting started)?

Tags: wgs84, cesium, great-circle

How does one plot Great circle lines in Cesium (3D, not 2D) using the WGS84 ellipsoid? I found something like this in [another thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194649/arcs-circle-segments-in-cesium) but I'm having trouble applying it to my application (simply plotting great circle PolyLines of a given width and colour.

Also, I noticed that Google Maps have [a light blue line within a dark blue line.](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Vancouver+International+Airport,+3211+Grant+McConachie+Way,+Richmond,+BC+V7B+0A4,+Canada/Munich+International+Airport,+Nordallee+25,+85356+Freising,+Germany/@64.1096581,-57.395929,5000537m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x54860b348627a39b:0xba68ccac86348084!2m2!1d-123.1815123!2d49.1966913!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e135923da6d45:0xe3c57a853a56cf4b!2m2!1d11.7750279!2d48.3536621!3e4) Is it possible to draw this on Cesium in one go, or should I use two separate lines? And how would I place markers at the beginning and end?

As you can see, I'm just getting started with Cesium, but I would like some insight.

I am trying to plot great circle lines between airports. The data for each airport is in a JSON object, and the sub-objects look like this:

```
var airportData = {
    ...
    "EDDM": {
        "icao": "EDDM",
        "iata": "MUC",
        "name": "Munich International Airport",
        "city": "Munich",
        "state": "Bavaria",
        "country": "DE",
        "elevation": 1487,
        "lat": 48.3538017273,
        "lon": 11.7861003876,
        "tz": "Europe\/Berlin"
    },
    ...
    "KSFO": {
        "icao": "KSFO",
        "iata": "SFO",
        "name": "San Francisco International Airport",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "California",
        "country": "US",
        "elevation": 13,
        "lat": 37.6189994812,
        "lon": -122.375,
        "tz": "America\/Los_Angeles"
    }
    ...
}
```

And the function to actually plot the lines:

```
function plotLine(start, end)
{
    var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("map");

    var origin_lat = start.lat;
    var origin_lon = start.lon;
    var dest_lat = end.lat;
    var dest_lon = end.lon;

    // What goes here?
}
```

And if someone could put an example that works in the [Cesium Sandcastle](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html) that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Polyline for something like this.  [Here's a live demo.](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?#c=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)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var airportData = {
    "EDDM": {
        "icao": "EDDM",
        "iata": "MUC",
        "name": "Munich International Airport",
        "city": "Munich",
        "state": "Bavaria",
        "country": "DE",
        "elevation": 1487,
        "lat": 48.3538017273,
        "lon": 11.7861003876,
        "tz": "Europe\/Berlin"
    },
    "KSFO": {
        "icao": "KSFO",
        "iata": "SFO",
        "name": "San Francisco International Airport",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "state": "California",
        "country": "US",
        "elevation": 13,
        "lat": 37.6189994812,
        "lon": -122.375,
        "tz": "America\/Los_Angeles"
    }
};

function plotLine(start, end, name)
{
    var origin_lat = start.lat;
    var origin_lon = start.lon;
    var dest_lat = end.lat;
    var dest_lon = end.lon;

    var line = viewer.entities.add({
        name : name,
        polyline : {
            positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([origin_lon, origin_lat,
                                                            dest_lon, dest_lat]),
            width : 7,
            material : new Cesium.PolylineOutlineMaterialProperty({
                color : Cesium.Color.DEEPSKYBLUE,
                outlineWidth : 4,
                outlineColor : Cesium.Color.DARKBLUE
            })
        }
    });

    return line;
}

plotLine(airportData.EDDM, airportData.KSFO, 'Path from EDDM to KSFO');

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

Comment: That was far easier than I expected. Thanks!